# Regular expression to parse data sectionised by brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to parse some data sectionised by square brackets.

Each data contains 3 sections with **fixed names and preset order**, which could be compared to meals.
(Sections identifiers: `<br />[Breakfast]<br />`, `<br />[Lunch]<br />`, `<br />[Dinner]<br />`)

But the problem is that the **some or all of the sections of each data may not exist** as exemplified below, and the content **may contain pairs of brackets** to provide additional information.
(but does never contain the identifiers within.)

**Sample Data:**

- `20181225<br />[Breakfast]<br />Fish finger sandwich [400 kcal]<br />Jellied eels<br />[Lunch]<br />Pork pies [500 kcal]<br />[Dinner]<br />Stargazy pies`
- `20181226<br />[Dinner]<br />Stargazy pies`
- `20181227<br />[Breakfast]<br />Fish finger sandwich [400 kcal]<br />Jellied eels<br />[Dinner]<br />Stargazy pies`
- `20181228`

**Desired Ouput:**
`$date: 20181225`
`$breakfast: Fish finger sandwich [400 kcal]<br />Jellied eels`
`$lunch: Pork pies [500 kcal]`
`$dinner: Stargazy pies`

`$date: 20181226`
`$dinner: Stargazy pies`

`$date: 20181227`
`$breakfast: Fish finger sandwich [400 kcal]<br />Jellied eels`
`$dinner: Stargazy pies`

`$date: 20181228`

I've tried regex below, but doesn't work properly as **the greedy quantifier ignores following sections even if they exist**.

`(?<date>\d{8})(?:<br \/>\[Breakfast\]<br \/>(?<breakfast>.*))?(?:<br \/>\[Lunch\]<br \/>(?<lunch>.*))?(?:<br \/>\[Dinner\]<br \/>(?<dinner>.*))?`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: @Jan I'm working on C#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to, at the end of every optional group, lookahead for `$` or `<br`, right after lazy-repeating `.`. Also anchor the end of the match to the end of the string, to ensure that every sub-group that can be matched will be matched:

```
(?<date>\d{8})(?:<br \/>\[Breakfast\]<br \/>(?<breakfast>.*?(?=$|<br)))?(?:<br \/>\[Lunch\]<br \/>(?<lunch>.*?(?=$|<br)))?(?:<br \/>\[Dinner\]<br \/>(?<dinner>.*))?$
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/vtCLoX/1

If you can't count on the string containing *just* that data, then using the `$`s won't work - instead, after `Breakfast`, repeat while making sure you don't come across `Lunch|Dinner`, and after `Lunch`, repeat while making sure you don't come accross `Dinner`:

```
(?<date>\d{8})(?:<br \/>\[Breakfast\]<br \/>(?<breakfast>(?:(?!<br \/>\[(Lunch|Dinner)\]).)+))?(?:<br \/>\[Lunch\]<br \/>(?<lunch>(?:(?!<br \/>\[Dinner).)+))?(?:<br \/>\[Dinner\]<br \/>(?<dinner>.*))?
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/vtCLoX/3